# VC++ error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'pFirst'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am new to C++, but I do pretty well at C# and Java. I am trying to do some basic exercise here:

```
// HelloWorld.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isSame(int[] pFirst, int[] pSecond, int pLength) {

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    return 0;
}
```

That is my entire file, but VC++ (I am using VS 2013) keeps complaining:

```
1   IntelliSense: expected a ')'
```

at the `isSame` declaration line.

What do I do wrong? I am writing a function to compare if two arrays are containing the same values, and here is the solution:

```
bool ArrayEq( int A1[], int A2[], int size ) {
  for (int k=0; k<size; k++) {
    if (A1[k] != A2[k]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below: Don´t get used to "using namespace" and "TCHAR", "_tmain" in the first place.

Comment: @deviantfan thank you. For anyone who comes later, this explains why you shouldn't use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would be `int pFirst[]`.

But first of all this function already exists in the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal), and second
`std::vector` overloads [`operator ==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp).

Both should be prefered over handcrafted code and `std::vector` is better than a C-style array.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) I am new and feeling so many things to learn. That was precious information.